# dateString appears different on ipad than simulator

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My fetch request below:

```
if (_fetchedResultsController!=nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PortfolioAssetNews" inManagedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:30];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = nil;
NSSortDescriptor *byCreatedDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timestampCreated" ascending:NO];
sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: byCreatedDate, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"toAssetDetail = %@", [self.theAssetnews toAssetDetail]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] sectionNameKeyPath:@"pubDate" cacheName:@"PortfolioNews"];
return _fetchedResultsController;
```

//nslog below appears like May 23, 2013 in the simulator but like 2013-05-23 on ipad.
It is stored like this in the table as a string: May 23, 2013

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
NSLog(@"sectioninfo name==%@",[sectionInfo name]);
return [sectionInfo name];
```

}

I have tried dateformatter but it is showing null.
anyone knows what is happening?

Comment: What is `[sectionInfo name]`?  NSString?  NSDate

Comment: @lnafziger it should be NSString matching the return type of the method.

Comment: @Moxy: "should be", yes.  However he wants to use it with a date formatter which implies that it might be an NSDate....  Not to mention the fact that the format is changing, leading me to believe that it is indeed an NSDate.

Comment: @lnafziger Ok! You've got to wait for confirmation then.

Comment: its a nsstring....and it prints as May 23, 2013 in simulator...which is how it is in db....and thats what I want...but on the device..its...2013-05-23...does not make sense

Comment: because it is a nsstring that is why dateformatter isn't working...the only reason I am using date formatter is because of the issue mentione d above with device

Comment: My guess is that different formats are stored.  This could be because of a locale difference between simulator and device, eg.

Comment: and what can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

The simulator is always in US locale, sounds like your iPad is in a different one.